# URL Friendly Username in PHP?

Tags: php, string, friendly-url, slug

On my PHP site, currently users login with an email address and a password.  I would like to add a username as well, this username they g\set will be unique and they cannot change it.  I am wondering how I can make this name have no spaces in it and work in a URL so I can use there username to link to there profiles and other stuff.  If there is a space in there username then it should add an underscore jason_davis.  I am not sure the best way to do this?

Comment: There are plenty questions like this. Didn’t you get an answer with searching?

Comment: @Gumbo I searched SO, not google.  Possibly not the correct term but I did search for "URL friendly username" with not much luck.  I didn't know it was called a slug before this.

Comment: Maybe not everyone is trying to convert usernames. But searching for “URL friendly string” is returning usable results.

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5305879

Comment: Nowadays, you can use libraries like https://github.com/cocur/slugify or https://github.com/ausi/slug-generator to achieve that.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

```
function Slug($string)
{
    // convert to entities
    $string = htmlentities( $string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8' );
    // regex to convert accented chars into their closest a-z ASCII equivelent
    $string = preg_replace( '~&([a-z]{1,2})(?:acute|cedil|circ|grave|lig|orn|ring|slash|th|tilde|uml);~i', '$1', $string );
    // convert back from entities
    $string = html_entity_decode( $string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8' );
    // any straggling caracters that are not strict alphanumeric are replaced with a dash
    $string = preg_replace( '~[^0-9a-z]+~i', '-', $string );
    // trim / cleanup / all lowercase
    $string = trim( $string, '-' );
    $string = strtolower( $string );
    return $string;
}

$user = 'Alix Axel';
echo Slug($user); // alix-axel

$user = 'Álix Ãxel';
echo Slug($user); // alix-axel

$user = 'Álix----_Ãxel!?!?';
echo Slug($user); // alix-axel
```

Comment: This is dangerous! Multiple unique user names can map to the same URL. That's not what you want, is it? Consider, e.g., `AB` and `ab`, which are unique strings but map to the same slug string. You should store the slug as the identifier.

Comment: @John Feminella: He would obviously have to check for duplicates at some point before storing the slug.

Comment: perfect, thank you.  BTW what does this part look for acute|cedil|circ|grave|lig|orn|ring|slash|th|tilde|uml ?

Comment: @jasondavis: För stüff lıkë thîs!

Comment: @Pekka: Thanks! =) @jasondavid: It removes accents, instead of having a huge lookup table we convert to html entities and fetch the unaccented char.

Comment: As a slight improvement, using `iconv()` to convert to `ASCII//TRANSLIT` would probably catch a lot more chars.

Comment: @Frank Farmer: `iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', 'Álix Ãxel')` returns `'Alix ~Axel`. Using PHP 5.3.0 and .php file encoded as UTF-8 **no** BOM.

Comment: Anyone know why Á and Ã would cause no output or error to occur when using this function?

Comment: I'll answer my own question: remove the "'UTF-8'" parameter from htmlentities. That did the trick.

Comment: @John Conde: I though you're talking about the `iconv()` function! You shouldn't remove the `UTF-8` from `htmlentities`, instead you should **save all your `.php` files encoded as UTF-8 no BOM**.

Comment: Alex, thanks for the info. I reutnred the "UTF-8" parameter and saved the file as UTF-8 and it worked like a charm.

Comment: @John Conde: No problem! ;) You should always save your files UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: This function does not convert Polish chars "ąćęłńóśźż" => "acelnoszz", because they have no names in html entities (only numeric representation). You still need to replace those with table. Paste below code before `return` in function: `$string = strtr(mb_strtolower($string), array('ą'=>'a','ć'=>'c','ę'=>'e','ł'=>'l','ń'=>'n','ó'=>'o','ś'=>'s','ź'=>'z','ż'=>'z'));`

Comment: @s3men: Indeed, not only Polish characters but others as well (Chinese, Japanese, Turkish, Arabic, ...).

Comment: After few more tests iconv made the trick, as someone wrote above.
`setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.utf8");
$string = iconv("UTF-8", "ascii//TRANSLIT", '>ĄĘŁŹÓżół<');` gives me `>AELZOzol<`

Comment: codepad demo of the `Slug()` function, with a second identical but spaced out `nSlug()` function (for the eyeball impaired): http://codepad.org/rJNSQmGJ

Answer (score 3):

In other words... you need to create a username slug. Doctrine (ORM for PHP) has a nice function to do it. [Doctrine_Inflector::urlize()](http://trac.doctrine-project.org/browser/branches/1.2/lib/Doctrine/Inflector.php)

**EDIT**: You should also keep username slug in database, as a Unique Key column. Then every search operation should be done based on that column, not original username.

Comment: Broken link... can now be found here: https://github.com/doctrine/inflector/blob/2.0.x/lib/Doctrine/Inflector/Inflector.php

Comment: Though, it's worth noting that this take the "keep a comprehensive list of all characters to replace" approach, which is much harder to maintain than the approach of the accepted answer.