# How to remove all special characters from URL?

Tags: php, string

I have my class

```
public function convert( $title )
    {
        $nameout = strtolower( $title );
        $nameout = str_replace(' ', '-', $nameout );
        $nameout = str_replace('.', '', $nameout);
        $nameout = str_replace('æ', 'ae', $nameout);
        $nameout = str_replace('ø', 'oe', $nameout);
        $nameout = str_replace('å', 'aa', $nameout);
        $nameout = str_replace('(', '', $nameout);
        $nameout = str_replace(')', '', $nameout);
        $nameout = preg_replace("[^a-z0-9-]", "", $nameout);    

        return $nameout;
    }
```

BUt I can't get it to work when I use special characters like `ö` and `ü` and other, can sombody help me here? I use PHP 5.3.

Comment: Why do you need to remove diacritics exactly? If it's just to have it pass inside an HTTP URL, you can use `urlencode`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first answer in [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2103797/url-friendly-username-in-php) contains the code you need to do this.

Comment: Tanks a lot, all i relly need.

Answer (score 2):

And what about:

```
<?php
$query_string = 'foo=' . urlencode($foo) . '&bar=' . urlencode($bar);
echo '<a href="mycgi?' . htmlentities($query_string) . '">';
?>
```

From: http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Comment: No sorry, becures its not make like "å" to "aa" nad if i'm not convert it i will be to "_" :)

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this function a while ago for a project I was working on and couldn't get RegEx to work. Its not the best way, but it works.

```
function safeURL($input){
    $input = strtolower($input);
    for($i = 0; $i < strlen($input); $i++){
        $working = ord(substr($input,$i,1));
        if(($working>=97)&&($working<=122)){
            //a-z
            $out = $out . chr($working);
        } elseif(($working>=48)&&($working<=57)){
            //0-9
            $out = $out . chr($working);
        } elseif($working==46){
            //.
            $out = $out . chr($working);
        } elseif($working==45){
            //-
            $out = $out . chr($working);
        }
    }
    return $out;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function to help with what you're doing, it's written in
Czech: http://php.vrana.cz/vytvoreni-pratelskeho-url.php
([and translated to English](http://translate.google.ca/translate?hl=en&sl=cs&u=http://php.vrana.cz/vytvoreni-pratelskeho-url.php&ei=sG2eS4XbMc2vtgfWxfyGBg&sa=X&oi=translate&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CA4Q7gEwAA&prev=/search%3Fq%3Dhttp://php.vrana.cz/vytvoreni-pratelskeho-url.php%26hl%3Den%26safe%3Doff%26client%3Dfirefox-a%26hs%3DOIZ%26rls%3Dorg.mozilla:en-US:official))

Here's another take on it ([from the Symfony documentation](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/08#chapter_08_adding_tests_because_of_a_bug)):

```
<?php 
function slugify($text)
{
  // replace non letter or digits by -
  $text = preg_replace('~[^\\pL\d]+~u', '-', $text);

  // trim
  $text = trim($text, '-');

  // transliterate
  if (function_exists('iconv'))
  {
    $text = iconv('utf-8', 'us-ascii//TRANSLIT', $text);
  }

  // lowercase
  $text = strtolower($text);

  // remove unwanted characters
  $text = preg_replace('~[^-\w]+~', '', $text);

  if (empty($text))
  {
    return 'n-a';
  }

  return $text;
}
```