# Remove a character "~" from URL in jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am redirecting to a specific page after button click in jquery ajax success function

I have this code with me:

```
$.ajax({
   // additional code omitted
   success:function(data) {
         var value = JSON.parse(data.d);
        window.location.href = "https://www.example.com" + value.dataSet.Table[0].RedirectURL;
        }  
 });
```

Now I am getting value of **value.dataSet.Table[0].RedirectURL** as "~/myPost.aspx"

So the complete url becomes : https://www.example.com/~/myPost.aspx

To avoid this I had done something like this:

```
var url = "https://www.example.com" + "~/myPost.aspx"
window.location.href= url.replace("~","");
```

But this code doesn't redirect me to new page. It stays where it is.

What should be done to remove the tilde sign (**~**) from the URL such that it becomes like https://www.example.com/myPost.aspx Jquery Ajax?

**EDIT:**

**My second attempt:**

I have tried to remove the first character as I have **~** only at the beginning of the URL.

```
    function removeChar(str) {
        let temp = str.split('');
        return temp.slice(1).join('');
    }
```

and then...

```
    $.ajax({
   // additional code omitted
   success:function(data) {
         var value = JSON.parse(data.d);
        let inputURL = value.dataSet.Table[0].RedirectURL;
        let outputURL = removeChar(inputURL); // this gets /myPost.aspx but it doesn't redirect after this line.
        window.location.href = "http://www.example.com/" + outputURL;
     }  
 });
```

**Note:** The value of ** value.dataSet.Table[0].RedirectURL** is **~/myPost.aspx**

In this case, it is not redirecting to the desired page. The page reloads and stays where it is.

Comment: Your second snippet works correctly for me

Comment: But it doesn't work for me. Is it related to browser anyway ?

Comment: @Axnyff it just reloads the page and stays where it is. It doesn't redirect in my case

Comment: This question may already have an answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448951/how-to-remove-all-special-characters-from-url

Comment: Are there multiple `~` characters in your url? You're only replacing the first one with your code

Comment: @Axnyff, No. It is only at the beginning of the 'value.dataSet.Table[0].RedirectURL' value..Please see my edit also.

Comment: You can use directly slice on your string. Your code should work, unless the value you get from the server is difference than what you expect

Comment: @Axnyff, is there any other way?