# create SEO links in PHP

Tags: php, seo

what is the best preg_replace to create an SEOed text to be used in uri ??

i mean like if we had this uri `http://t.com/SOME RANDOM $#@ TEXT _ + ?/ =\` , what is best preg_replace expression to clean it up ?

Thank you .

**EDIT :** assuming you have multiple languages in the random text language ??

Comment: @BoltClock : yes , that is not a valid URI , lets assume that `SOME RANDOM $#@ TEXT _ + ?/ =\` is some entry from a database , and you want to use it in that position in that URI , how would you make it valid ? .

Comment: @Gumbo : hmmm , i think a valid string that is accepted in a URI as a single parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean a slug?

```
Slug('SOME RANDOM $#@ TEXT _ + ?/ =\\'); // some-random-text
```

For that this should be enough:

```
function Slug($string, $slug = '-')
{
    return strtolower(trim(preg_replace('~[^0-9a-z]+~i', $slug, $string), $slug));
}
```

Comment: assuming you have multiple languages in the random text language ??

Comment: @Ronan: For that, see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2103797/url-friendly-username-in-php/2103815#2103815.

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you're looking for is URL sanitizing. Here's a link to a filter for php: http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php