# How to handle invalid encoded URL's

Tags: php

I'm wondering how you're supposed to handle invalid encoded URL's in PHP. PHP's urldecode decodes invalid encoded querystrings. See example below.

```
// % is invalid here, it should have been encoded but was not.
$url = 'http://www.test.com/?invalid_parameter=t%C3%A9kst%ads';
$parsedUrl = parse_url($url);
// parse_str automatically urldecode's it.
parse_str($parsedUrl['query'], $output);
// Outputs: tékst�s
var_dump($output['invalid_parameter']);
```

How can I either detect or remove the invalid placed %, which is resulting in a UTF-8 replacement character?

Comment: Where are these invalidly encoded querystrings coming from? Best thing is don't invalidly encode them in the first place.

Comment: @developerwjk This is what I'm getting from an API, I have no control over this. If I had control I would obvisouly change the URL but I'm trying to catch their error here.

Comment: What's the desired output here?

Comment: Maybe reality is different than you expect: maybe this is actually a url parameter that has not been encoded at all. So meant literally as string containing percent chars. Sure, invalid, but happens when newbees implement a API. And it would explain the sequence.

Comment: @arkascha is completely right. You cannot use `parse_str` which implements `urldecode()` on a URL string that was incorrectly encoded in the first place.

Comment: Kevin Lee: i would like to be able to detect that there's a UTF-8 replacement character in the string so I'm able to handle this 'error'. @arkascha you'd be surprised who this 'newbee' is.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I completly agree, but how can I prevent this if there's no way of knowing the URL is wrongly encoded?

Comment: I doubt I'd be surprised. Been in the business long enough and played with the big ones. Just humans :-) Except if that is a google API. Then I'd say: was to be expected.

Comment: found this two post on SO, hope if it helps, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/910793/detect-encoding-and-make-everything-utf-8, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20025030/convert-all-types-of-smart-quotes-with-php/21491305#21491305 . I personally know nothing about encoding except it should functioned it return a proper desired output...