# How to convert apostrophe or quotes in url string?

Tags: php, character-encoding, special-characters

I am trying to convert the apostrophe in URL string using htmlentities() or htmlspecialchars() .... but it is not working for me...

I have following code:

```
<?php
$new = htmlspecialchars("<a href='http://abc.test.net/content/22799-mdsap-partners-with-sap’s-‘moving-experience’-initiative-in-the-uae-and-oman'>Test</a>");
echo $new;
?>
```

but I am getting the output from $new:

```
<a href='http://abc.test.net/content/22799-mdsap-partners-with-sap’s-‘moving-experience’-initiative-in-the-uae-and-oman'>Test</a>
```

How to convert the apostrophe and single quotes in url...

Comment: Convert them into _what_?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert all types of smart quotes with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20025030/convert-all-types-of-smart-quotes-with-php) - FYI, yours are a variant of the "smart quotes" and if you do make them apostrophes then use the `ENT_QUOTES` flag when using `htmlspecialchars`.

Comment: I think you might want URL encoding, not HTML entities …

Answer (score 1):

Try to use **urlencode("*your URL*")** only on the part you need (otherwise it will mess up the rest of the URL):

```
$new = "<a href='http://abc.test.net/content/" . urlencode("22799-mdsap-partners-with-sap’s-‘moving-experience’-initiative-in-the-uae-and-oman") . "'>Test</a>";
echo $new;
```