# UTF-8 Convert problems

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding

i try to fix very easy problem, but in fact....it is hell !

In CSV file i got the following string :

```
"Couleur d’étagère"
```

The apostroph is in msword format, and i want to replace the char by a true apostroph.

So, in my result, following string is displayed :

[image]

I use some tricks listed in these questions :

[How to replace Microsoft-encoded quotes in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262038/how-to-replace-microsoft-encoded-quotes-in-php)

[how to replace apostrophe (’) with single quote(')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42932839/how-to-replace-apostrophe-with-single-quote/)

If i apply this answer :

```
function convert_smart_quotes($string) 
{ 
    $search = array(chr(145), 
                    chr(146), 
                    chr(147), 
                    chr(148), 
                    chr(151)); 

    $replace = array("'", 
                     "'", 
                     '"', 
                     '"', 
                     '-'); 

    return str_replace($search, $replace, $string); 
}
```

It works, the bad apostroph is well replaced, but i obtain very strange result, and i dont know why :'(

[image]

Comment: I found the question you lifted this solution from, and I'm confused why you lifted code from the _question_ and not the _answer_.

Comment: Thank you so much, i dont understand why, but the answer linked to this post seems to fix my problem.