# Replace characters in PHP but no more than once

Tags: php

What's best performing script to replace certain characters with a *maximum* of one other character?

For instance, I need to replace all spaces () and commas (`,`) with plus signs (`+`) **but no more than one plus sign at a time**

So: `the,quick, brown  fox jumped,   over the,, lazy, dog`

Would become: `the+quick+brown+fox+jumped+over+the+lazy+dog`

Comment: What you're asking for is called "slug". You may find some ready snippets here and there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5305879/automatic-clean-and-seo-friendly-url-slugs, http://code.google.com/p/php-slugs/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use a regular expression for this:

```
$text = 'the,quick, brown fox jumped, over the,, lazy, dog';
$newText = preg_replace('/[ ,+]+/', '+', $text);
```

Comment: To have it look a little bit nicer take `\s` for a whitespace :) Not mandatory, but I think it's always a bit about make up too

Comment: @DanLee:  Yeah, he probably meant whitespace characters, but he only said spaces, so I didn't use `\s` in case he didn't want tabs, newlines, etc. being replaced as well.

Comment: Okay my thoughts were that `\s` covers more than a plain white space (some ord values etc). And I dont think that `\s` covers tabs (`\t`) and new lines (`\n` or `\r\n`). But your argument is valid so this should do the job.

Comment: @DanLee: In PCRE, `\s` covers spaces, tabs `\t`, newlines `\n`, carriage returns `\r`, vertical tabs `\v`, and form feeds `\f`.  In PHP's implementation, vertical tabs `\v` don't seem to be matched by `\s` (not sure if this is a bug or intentional omission), but the others are.

Comment: If anyone cares, here's an explanation of whitespace classification: http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.differences.php.  It looks like the omission of `\v` from being matched by `\s` is intentional and it explains why.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
echo preg_replace('/[, ]+/', '+', 'the,quick, brown fox jumped, over the,, lazy, dog') . PHP_EOL;
```