# PHP preg replace for clean url

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

**what is best solution for this replacing?** *fast and optimized*

my link:

`https://example.com/event/123/Kinda Don't Care2 Feat. Jaba/Country Music (1990)`

I want clean to:

`https://example.com/event/123/Kinda-Dont-Care2-Feat-Jaba/Country-Music-1990`

`preg_replace('???????', '-', $strUrl);`

**Edit:**

`$str1 = "Kinda Don't Care2 Feat. Jaba";`

`$str2 = "Country Music (1990)"`;

replace to :

`$str1 = "Kinda-Dont-Care2-Feat-Jaba";`

`$str2 = "Country-Music-1990"`;

thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automatic clean and SEO friendly URL (slugs)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5305879/automatic-clean-and-seo-friendly-url-slugs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$string = "example.com/event/123/Kinda Don't Care2 Feat. Jaba/Country Music (1990)";

    // remove all non alphanumeric characters except spaces
    $clean =  preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/', '', strtolower($html)); 

    // replace one or multiple spaces into single dash (-)
    $clean =  preg_replace('!\s+!', '-', $clean); 

    echo $clean;
```

ref- [Automatic clean and SEO friendly URL (slugs)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5305879/automatic-clean-and-seo-friendly-url-slugs)