# PHP strip string of everything but letters and spaces, then convert spaces to dashes

Tags: php, regex, string

This is what I've tried, but it didn't remove the apostrophe, is there a better way to do it?

```
$title = strtr($title, array('.' => '', ',' => '', '!' => '', '\''  => ''));
$title = preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', $title);
```

So for example I would want to turn:

Example:

```
Let's Start! => lets-start
```

But I'm trying to find a solution that works for all cases.

Comment: You want uppercase to become lower case? Why does your code have underscore, when you want a dash?

Comment: first replace `[^\w\d\s]` with empty string, then replace `[\s]` with dash

Comment: @IlyaBursov I don't know too much regex or how to do that.

Comment: then read any manual about regexp first

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5305879/automatic-clean-and-seo-friendly-url-slugs

Comment: @IlyaBursov: characters from `\d` are already in `\w`, writing `[^\w\d\s]` is redundant and same as `[^\w\s]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use this expression:

```
strtolower(preg_replace("#\s+#u", "-", preg_replace("#[^\w\s]|_#u", "", $title)))
```

Note: if your original string contains HTML encoding, like `&#8217;`, then you must first decode it with:

```
$title = html_entity_decode($title);
```

Comment: That turned Let's Start! into let8217s-start

Comment: Sounds like you're not dealing with an ASCII apostrophe there, @JamesMitchell.

Comment: Try with the `u` (Unicode) modifier (answer updated). Also make sure your input string is not HTML encoded. It should really be a literal quote, not `#&8217;` like in HTML encoding.

Comment: Hmm yeah it may be a wordpress issue with the apostrophe because that part still doesn't work.

Comment: That's the issue I was trying to solve! Didn't realize I had to decode it. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = mb_strtolower( strtr("Let's start!", array('.' => '', ',' => '', '!' => '', '\''  => '') ) );
echo  $string = preg_replace("/[\s]/", "-", $string);
```

This should replace the characters, then change all spaces to dashes for you.

Comment: Having an issue with the apostrophe, I think it could be a wordpress issue. It's pulling the_title variable.

Comment: @JamesMitchell The variation would be to use `"'" => ''` instead. (Double quotes surrounding the single quote)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the same result without **regx**

### Example:

```
$title = "Let's Start!";
$title = strtr(strtolower($title), array('.' => '', ',' => '', '!' => '', '\''  => ''));
$title = str_replace(' ','-',trim($title));

echo $title; //Output: lets-start
```