# Turning a name into a URL-friendly string in PHP?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [URL Friendly Username in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2103797/url-friendly-username-in-php)

I have something like this:

```
'mrt1' => 'Zhongxiao Dunhua Sun'
```

which will be included into an anchor link like this:

```
<a href="'. $mrt1 .'">'. $mrt1 .'</a>
```

I want the output to be something like this:

```
<a href="zhongxiao-dunhua-sun">Zhongxiao Dunhua Sun</a>
```

How to do it so that I can turn that name into a URL-frienly string (so I can place it in the href attribute)?

Comment: You mean remove everything but the alphanumeric characters? (And do lower case?)

Comment: @Jared Farrish Yeah, and add the slashes between the words I guess

Comment: Whoops, I thought this was for Javascript. So... `'Zhongxiao Dunhua Sun'.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '-').replace(/[^a-z\-]/gi, '');`

Comment: @Jared Farrish ha that's for JavaScript? Thanks too.

Comment: @hakre - You seem a little cranky... `:)` That function is funky, but does cover the territory I was thinking it should (with special characters and etc.).

Comment: @alexchenco - I did a demo with some different possibilities: http://codepad.org/rJNSQmGJ Alix Axel's `oSlug()` in his linked (by @hakre) answer looks with my somewhat limited test to work the best. @leepowers version, while close, doesn't handle some special characters. Also, I reformatted Alex's `oSlug()` function so it is easier to read; see `nSlug()`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
$s = ' Zhongxiao Dunhua Sun ';
$r = preg_replace('/\W+/', '-', strtolower(trim($s)));
echo("$r\n");
```

- Replaces [non-word characters](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php) with dashes
- Converts to lowercase

Comment: Shouldn't you `trim()` pre-regex?

Comment: There are a couple of issues with this and special characters and newlines: http://codepad.org/rJNSQmGJ

Comment: Running this code didn't change the string at all for me.

Comment: Good, but incomplete. It is missing `$s= trim($s, '-');` after `preg_replace`. Also you should not use 1 letter variables for readability purpose.

Answer (score 3):

PHP has a function for making strings conform to URL standards:

```
urlencode($mrt1);
```

Comment: The OP may not want to use `+` (for design reasons...). That is a reasonable suggestion, though.

Comment: Just this one single approach can have some (at least visually) horror-show outcomes: http://codepad.org/rJNSQmGJ So much for "pretty" urls...

Answer (score 2):

You ca try this function also..

```
function create_seo_link($text) {
    $letters = array(
        '–', '—', '"', '"', '"', '\'', '\'', '\'',
        '«', '»', '&', '÷', '>',    '<', '$', '/'
    );

    $text = str_replace($letters, " ", $text);
    $text = str_replace("&", "and", $text);
    $text = str_replace("?", "", $text);
    $text = strtolower(str_replace(" ", "-", $text));

    return ($text);
}
```

Comment: I don't get this at all. Regular expressions do *sometimes* make perfect sense. `;)` But, seeing your function name, is this from a software package or library?

Comment: no i have created it..@JaredFarrish

Comment: Take a look at answer for the question Hakre links to in his comment above. I would say that's perhaps a more comprehensive approach, if a bit impenetrable to read.

Comment: @JaredFarrish Got Ur Point. Thanks.

Comment: Some different demos: http://codepad.org/rJNSQmGJ

Comment: really nice function nslug()..@JaredFarrish

Answer (score 0):

[str_replace()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) to change spaces to `-`, and [strtolower()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php) to change to lowercase.

```
$mrt1 = 'Zhongxiao Dunhua Sun';
$mrt1 = str_replace(' ','-',strtolower($mrt1));
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure this would cover all cases (such as special characters the OP might not want left in, like `*%$.?` etc.). It might not matter, but it is a big gap.

Comment: True, but based off his example, this simple example would work. If he has more stringent requirements, @leepowers' answer is a better solution.