# Making strings "URL safe"

Tags: php, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [URL Friendly Username in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2103797/url-friendly-username-in-php)

Is there a way to make strings "URL safe" which means replacing whitespaces with hyphens, removing any punctuation and change all capital letters to lowercase?

For example:

```
"This is a STRING" -› "this-is-a-string"
```

or

```
"Hello World!" –› "hello-world"
```

Comment: Of course - in which language?

Comment: What would be the easiest way? (I would prefer PHP to JavaScript.)

Comment: Yes, there most certainly is. [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: The answer to this question is hidden away in the source code of wordpress. Look for an ajax call that creates the slug for your post basing on the title.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `preg_replace` to replace change those characters.

```
$safe = preg_replace('/^-+|-+$/', '', strtolower(preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/', '-', $string)));
```

Comment: Is there an easy way to get rid of the last hyphen when the string ends with a special character?

Comment: @user1706680 Yes. I edited the answer to get rid of heading and trailing hyphens.

Answer (score 2):

I Often use this function to generate my clean urls and seems to work fine,
     You could alter it according to your needs but give it a try.

```
function sanitize($string, $force_lowercase = true, $anal = false) {
    $strip = array("~", "`", "!", "@", "#", "$", "%", "^", "&", "*", "(", ")", "_", "=", "+", "[", "{", "]",
                   "}", "\\", "|", ";", ":", "\"", "'", "&#8216;", "&#8217;", "&#8220;", "&#8221;", "&#8211;", "&#8212;",
                   "â€”", "â€“", ",", "<", ".", ">", "/", "?");
    $clean = trim(str_replace($strip, "", strip_tags($string)));
    $clean = preg_replace('/\s+/', "-", $clean);
    $clean = ($anal) ? preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $clean) : $clean ;
    return ($force_lowercase) ?
        (function_exists('mb_strtolower')) ?
            mb_strtolower($clean, 'UTF-8') :
            strtolower($clean) :
        $clean;
}
```