# Codeigniter blog application: avoid duplicate entry error for slug

Tags: php, codeigniter, slug, slugify

I am working on a basic **blog application** in Codeigniter 3.1.8 and Bootstrap 4. The `posts` table has a `slug` column that I intend to use at making SEO friendly URLs.

Because every individual post's slug will be a part of it's URL, the `slug` column is, of course, *unique*. I use CI's `url_title()` method to *make the slug out of the post title*:

```
$slug = url_title($this->input->post('title'), 'dash', TRUE);
```

Given the above described situation, it is obvious that a problem appears when 2 posts have the exact same title ("Who loves a butterfly?"):

```
Duplicate entry 'who-loves-a-butterfly' for key 'slug'
```

I need a way to make the duplicate title post generate a "numbered" slug: "who-loves-a-butterfly-1" and so on, if necessary.

The Codeigniter 3 documentation does not provide such a way for its `url_title()` method? Is there a way I could modify it or an alternative to it?

Comment: As I understand, your problem is duplicate key in database. `url_title` just convert a string to url format and do nothing with database. You must write a custom function to check if `slug` existed on DB or not.

Comment: Nonce the slug and you're golden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot of creative approaches you could use. It all depends on your personal preference.

The first one, with query builder enabled would be to use the built-in `form_validation` and check if your slug complies with `is_unique` and if it isn't, alter it slightly and re-check until the validation passes. Even though `form_validation` is used mainly to validate and sanitize user input, you can use it for pretty much anything.

Another approach would be to always make sure you're getting a unique slug on the first try by appending a nonce or a random number or some other unique parameter to the generated slug before insertion. For example:

```
$slug = url_title($this->input->post('title'), 'dash', TRUE).strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
```

The above, which is probably the simplest approach possible, will work as long as no two posts with exactly the same title are created at the exact same second. That would reduce the chance of collisions (almost) entirely.

A third solution, a little bit more cumbersome, would involve calculating the base slug with `$slug = url_title($this->input->post('title'), 'dash', TRUE);` and then:

1.- pass the slug to a simple database query (either right there in the controller or inside a model, your choice)

```
$this->db->select('count(*) as slugcount');
$this->db->from('your_table');
$this->db->where('slug', $slug);

$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->row(0)->slugcount;
```

If the slug is truly unique, you'll be returned 0, if there's one previous entry you'll be returned 1 and so on.

Afterwards you choose:
The first time you create a slug, append a "-0" or a "-1" (depending on what's best for SEO)
The second time you append a "-1" or a "-2" (depending on what you defined in the previous one) 
and so on and so on

So, for example, you would alter your slug with

```
$slug = $slug."-".$slugcount;
```

would that work?

Comment: A simple, creative solution. Still, not SEO friendly.

Comment: Just curious... what would you consider SEO friendly? I'm on a break and perhaps I could help you figure this one out

Comment: added a third non-native alternative which I believe adheres better to the end result you are looking for

Comment: It worked perfectly. See how I applied your solution in my application **[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52791768/4512005)**. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a custom function sanitize() - normally in a model - to create that unique slug entry:
please read code comment as it documents the flow

```
function sanitize($string,$table='posts'){
    // sanitize string, remove Latin chars like 'ç ' and add - instead of white-space
    // based on: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2103815/2275490
    $str= strtolower(trim(preg_replace('~[^0-9a-z]+~i', '-', html_entity_decode(preg_replace('~&([a-z]{1,2})(?:acute|cedil|circ|grave|lig|orn|ring|slash|th|tilde|uml);~i', '$1', htmlentities($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')), '-'));
    // check how often header exists in table "posts"
    // add counted suffix to pretty_url if already exists
    $query = $this->db  ->where('slug', $string)
                        ->get($table);
    if($query->num_rows()>0) 
        $str=$str.'-'.$query->num_rows(); // allways returns the latest number for same slug

    return $str;                    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full solution applied in my blog application:

In the **Posts_model** model:

```
public function slug_count($slug){
    $this->db->select('count(*) as slugcount');
    $this->db->from('posts');
    $this->db->where('slug', $slug);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->row(0)->slugcount;
}

public function create_post($post_image, $slug) {
    $data = [
        'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
        'slug' => $slug,
        'description' => $this->input->post('desc'),
        'content' => $this->input->post('body'),
        'post_image' => $post_image,
        'author_id' => $this->session->userdata('user_id'),
        'cat_id' => $this->input->post('category'),
        'created_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
    ];
    return $this->db->insert('posts', $data);
}
```

In the **Posts** controller:

```
// Create slug (from title)
$slug = url_title($this->input->post('title'), 'dash', TRUE);
$slugcount = $this->Posts_model->slug_count($slug);
if ($slugcount > 0) {
    $slug = $slug."-".$slugcount;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a function which will create always unique slug for any table.
**In Model**

```
function get_unique_slug($slug,$table)
{
$slug = url_title($this->input->post('title'), 'dash', TRUE);
$this->db->select('count(*) as slugcount');
$this->db->from($table);
$this->db->where('slug like', $slug.'%');

$query = $this->db->get();
if($query->row(0)->slugcount>0)
{
    return $slug.'-'.$query->row(0)->slugcount;
}
else
{
    return $slug;
}
}
```

**In Controller**

```
$slug = $this->crud_model->get_unique_slug($slug,'category');
```